# some problems when i import googlecast demo

Tags: android

I had added 
`android-support-v4.jar`,
`android-support-v7-appcompat.jar`,
`android-support-v7-midearouter.jar`,

and I had added the "`GooleCastSdkAndroid`" as a lib project.
But it still reported an error:

```
[2013-10-22 10:21:21 - CastSampleActivity] W/ResourceType( 8256): ResXMLTree_node header size 0 is too small.<br/>
[2013-10-22 10:21:21 - CastSampleActivity] cast-android-sample-master\cast-android-sample-master\res\menu\cast_sample.xml:3: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'actionProviderClass' in package 'com.example.castsample'<br/>
[2013-10-22 10:21:21 - CastSampleActivity]cast-android-sample-master\cast-android-sample-master\res\menu\cast_sample.xml:3: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'com.example.castsample'.
```

Can someone help to point me Where Is Wrong?

Comment: What is your minSdk in your manifest ?

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

Comment: If you are building with Eclipse, make sure your project's build target is set to Honeycomb too.

Comment: I has tried several times accordance with the document "README_ECLIPSE.txt" in the sample(cast-android-sample-master) file, but it still has the error issue.I really do not know how to do it.

Comment: I had the same issue...Any helps will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem.

Please change

`app:actionProviderClass` to `android:actionProviderClass`

`app:showAsAction` to `android:showAsAction`.